# Display GUI on single machine in Vagrant Cluster

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I am launching a cluster of VM's using Vagrant. I want to have only a single machine display it's GUI. The only means I've found to turn on the GUI is with

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.gui = true
end
```

Unfortunately, this makes all VM's in my cluster display a GUI. Does anyone know of a way to restrict this to a single machine?

Comment: Long shot, did you ever find an answer to this question?

Answer (score -3):

I simply turn on X11 port forwarding. That makes my graphic programs display on the host machine.